# Text field validation

Tags: iphone

I want to validate my text field with a `YYYY` format, meaning a user can only enter a four digit number like a year. There are seven text fields including this text field; I only want this text field to require validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are sample for validate text field.

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
       If(textField == myTextField)
       {

         if ([textField length] > 4)
         {
             return NO;
         }
        NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

        NSNumber* candidateNumber;

        NSString* candidateString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        range = NSMakeRange(0, [candidateString length]);

        [numberFormatter getObjectValue:&candidateNumber forString:candidateString range:&range error:nil];

        if (([candidateString length] > 0) && (candidateNumber == nil || range.length < [candidateString length])) {

            return NO;
        }
        else 
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: If(textField == myTextField)
 here we get error ,,that expting"" before tocken somthing like that

Comment: myTextField means, write your uitextfield, on which you want to validation.

Comment: error againm,if(textfield == year)  "implicit diclaration of function if"

Comment: Bhalara its works for me,,but i want to validate this textfield with only entering four numbers,because its a year entering textfield

Comment: See my updated code, I have add one condition to check the length of textfield.

Answer (score 1):

1. Give the keyboard type to be numeric in the interface builder.
2. Implement the UITextFieldDelegate and in the assign the delegate of the text field to the controller class which holds it
3. Implement the textfielddidendediting delegate method and validate your input.

Create a regex as below

```
NSString *number = @"[0-9]"; 
    NSPredicate *numbertest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", number]; 
 if ([numbertest evaluateWithObject:yourtextfield.text] != YES)
{
// Display error message
}
```